# How many CP/M machines ever shipped?

Tags: history, cp-m, s-100

How many machines for which CP/M was the primary operating system (so not counting the Commodore 128) ever shipped?

I would also be interested in knowing how many S-100 machines ever shipped. I get the impression the two are almost synonymous?

Comment: The Heath H-89a supported two operating systems, HDOS and CP/M. Which of these two was the primary one? (P.S. It did not have an S-100 bus.)

Comment: Definitely lots. And S-100 was *one* of the bus systems popular during CP/M times - But certainly not the only one.

Comment: @traal I take an operational definition of primary operating system: which was the more commonly used in practice? E.g. the IBM PC supported four operating systems quite early on, but there's no question that MSDOS was the primary. Of course it would be ideal to be able to get actual numeric breakdown of which was used how often.

Comment: Immediately adding hugely to the non-S-100 count: the Amstrad PCW. Per Wikipedia (so, ummmm, yeah) that's close to 8m CP/M machines immediately (the last model it refers to barely sold).

Comment: Do things like the Sony line of word processors that run CP/M as the underlying OS count?

Comment: The count also depends on CP/M vs. CP/M family of operating systems - i.e., MP/M (multiuser), CP/M-86 (for 16-bit CPUs - this is what was available (but hardly sold any) for the IBM PC), MP/M-86 (16-bit and multiuser), Concurrent CPM (single user but multi-tasking - essentially MP/M with only one terminal), Concurrent DOS (multiuser with a moderate amount of MS-DOS compatibility), etc. All of those could be considered variants or descendants of CP/M, though I would leave off DR-DOS which was really a MS-DOS replacement and AFAIK does not have any CPM function call compatibility.

Comment: CCP/M-86 was really nice.

Comment: You could argue that CP/M was the primary operating system on the Commodore 128, since the machine boots in Z80 mode and gets transferred to the 8502 CPU only if CP/M isn't present in the floppy drive.

Comment: Thousands of CP/M based MicroBee PCs (the disk ones used CP/M) were sold in Australia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MicroBee

Comment: I'd say this question is almost impossible to answer. A lot of countries had their local computer manufacturer that now are no more, so the statistics is real hard to find...

Comment: @UncleBod Particularly the commie states tried to avoid the COCOM list by producing local clones. They had a quite well working local IT industry, however their actually shipped numbers was low (not because the quality, but because these states were not very good in high tech). Russia still has its own IT industry, these chips drive their rockets and planes. It is even licensed to China and to some ex-soviet states (maybe even to North Korea, but hush-hush).